# Chrome does not read image on canvas

Tags: image, google-chrome, html5-canvas

I am trying to read and load a image from javascript to html 5 canvas element. This works just fine in ubuntu mozilla and andriod mobile browser but ubuntu chrome does not show me the image. My code is as follows.

```
 function readImage() 
 {  
     var img = new Image();
     var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
     var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
     img.src = "img/1.jpg";
     img.onload = function ()
     {      
          ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
     };     
}

 window.onload = function (){
    readImage();
 }
```

Am I doing some thing wrong or is it just chrome messing with me just for fun of it..I attached a code with canvas and img element below.[image]

Comment: Chrome really sucks latly. So many bugs... Even IE has less for now.

Comment: Do you have any errors in dev console? For me it works in chrome (win 7). http://jsfiddle.net/Kienz/bQ4T5/

Comment: unfortunately no errors. I am working in Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could experience a Chrome bug related to `new Image` which fails in some versions ([a known issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=238071#c1) including version 27.0.1453.94 m on Windows 7).

Try with the following work-around using `document.createElement()` instead:

```
function readImage() {  

     var img = document.createElement('img'); // this will work in Chrome too

     var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
     var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

     img.onload = function() {      
          ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
     };
     img.src = "img/1.jpg";  // put src after onload
}

window.onload = readImage;
```